# Как перемешать записи в Б.Д?

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица состоящая из n количества записей. Нужно перемешать эти записи в случайном порядке.

Comment: В базах данных нет необходимости мешать записи. Наоборот, их нужно упорядочивать для быстрого поиска. `SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5` - вот запрос, который выбирает 5 случайных строк. Ещё  http://www.skalnyy.com/vybor-sluchajnyx-zapisej-sql/

Answer (score 1):

Получаете из базы массив всех записей, после этого перемешиваете массив с помощью `shuffle`

```
$results = range(1, 20);
shuffle($results );
foreach ($results as $item) {
    echo "$item ";
}
```

Comment: а как сделать что бы не было повторов?

Comment: каких повторов?